# Is the Use of Django Templates Common in Backend Python Jobs, or is it Typically Used Primarily for API and Business Logic Development?"

Tags: python, django, templates, backend

In the job market, I see many Python backend positions, and many of them require knowledge of the Django framework. However, as I started studying Django, I noticed that it uses templates as part of its architecture. In practice, are templates heavily used, or do companies typically have a frontend person using some JavaScript framework and a backend person using Django more for building APIs and implementing business logic? me as a Backend developer should focus in learn templates or learn build API in Django with Django rest?

I'm new to Django and exploring backend Python job opportunities. I've noticed that Django uses templates in its architecture, but I'm curious about the practical use of templates in the industry. Have you encountered a situation where Django templates are widely used in backend development roles, or is it more common for companies to have a frontend specialist using JavaScript frameworks while Django is primarily utilized for API development and business logic implementation?

Comment: This is not a general discussion site.   you might find one of the other StackOverflow sites to be better for this type of question.   Also maybe someplace on redit.    fwiw, I have seen both templates and custom javascript used to provide the GUI side of a site with django.  just depends on what the project calls for (more lively sites will require additional django libs or custom javascript).

Comment: if you want to ask people about their experiences, you should try to follow the guidelines in [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the evolving landscape of web development, the integration of frontend frameworks like React with Django's backend, powered by Django Rest Framework, has become increasingly common. At my place of work, for instance, we have used Django templates for years but since last year we started using React/Django Rest Framework to build new applications, leveraging the strengths of both.

While many backend positions mention Django expertise, the practical application can vary. Understanding Django templates can be beneficial, especially in scenarios where frontend and backend tasks are handled by the same developer. However, with the rise of specialized roles, it's also common for companies to have dedicated front-end developers working on JavaScript frameworks, leaving backend engineers to focus on Django Rest Framework for API development and business logic.

IMO, I think as a backend developer, having a solid grasp of Django templates is necessary, likewise the expertise in building APIs with Django Rest Framework aligns well with the current industry trends. Balancing both can make you a versatile developer, capable of contributing effectively in various team structures.